# unable to find cgi-bin directory

Tags: directory

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/21-intermediate-geoserver-tutorials/38-configuring-geoserver-proxy-for-public-and-remote-data-access.html) and it is asking me to save `proxy.cgi` in the `/var/www/cgi-bin` directory.

There is no directory in `www` with the name `cgi-bin`. Do I need to create a directory there? I think the tutorial's guidance is for a RPM-based linux distribution, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Ubuntu, the standard `cgi-bin` directory is `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`.

Comment: Can we create `cgi-bin` in `/var/www`??

Comment: You can if you want. Just update your apache config to find it there.

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu, could tell me how can i update apache config and what should i enter?

Comment: You'd change the `ScriptAlias` line in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` (or add one to applicable vhost)

Answer (score 0):

Most files should not be executed as CGI scripts. This would be very dangerous. CGI scripts should kept in a directory separate from and outside your DocumentRoot, and only this directory should have the ExecCGI option set. This is the default, and the default location for CGI scripts is /usr/lib/cgi-bin.